# GWT-Custom Button

Tags: gwt, button

I need a gwt widget which has a button and can display a number. The number indicates the number of updates present.

The best example of this implementation which i can think of is facebook. The notification button on the facebook homepage displays a number which indicates the number of notifications from the last login.

I want to implement something like that.

Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Use a button, and set the text to a number?

Answer (score 1):

you can use button and on every update ,change the label of the button to reflects the number of update , if you wanted it on a server side you can update the button name from a callback function